# Adding multiple image gallery's on one page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to add multiple slideshows on one page using HTML 5, CSS and JS to my Django app from [this example.](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_caption)

I get that this piece of code was not meant for multiple slideshows on one page, however, I can't seem to find out how to get it to work.

More specifically when I add a second slideshow It doesn't change the proper image gallery.

Comment: It depends on how you add the second slideshow. Have you mixed any variables/function names ? also please read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script wasn't written to support multiple slideshows on the same page however if you create an object and pass the wrapping `div`'s `id` you can make it work.

```
function SlideShow(id) {
    this.container = document.getElementById(id);
    this.leftBtn = this.container.querySelector('.w3-display-left');
    this.rightBtn = this.container.querySelector('.w3-display-right');
    this.slideIndex = 1;
    var that = this;

    this.init = function() {
        this.showDivs(this.slideIndex);
    };
    this.plusDivs = function(n) {
        this.showDivs(this.slideIndex += n);
    };
    this.showDivs = function(n) {
        var x = this.container.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) {this.slideIndex = 1}    
        if (n < 1) {this.slideIndex = x.length}
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        x[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    };
    this.leftBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        that.plusDivs(-1);
    });
    this.rightBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        that.plusDivs(1);
    });
}

var foo = new SlideShow('foo');
foo.init();

var bar = new SlideShow('bar');
bar.init();
```

HTML

```
<div id="foo" class="w3-content w3-display-container">...</div>
<div id="bar" class="w3-content w3-display-container">...</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zwsmcn3q/31/

Note: the slideshow code can be improved but that's out of scope for this answer.

Note: you can also write this as a class with ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes